# Flexbox: Equal height rows (each row should match the height of the tallest column)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to have equal height rows using `display: flex` & `flex-wrap: wrap;`?  I know each *column* in a row can easily be the same height, but can each *row* match the height of the tallest column?

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  flex: 0 1 32.5%;
  background: honeydew;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p><strong>THIS ROW SHOULD BE THE SAME HEIGHT</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p><strong>AS THIS ROW</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived ons of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and ssheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think – not without javascript.